# How to calculate risk ratio for chemical substances

Tags: r, binary-data, relative-risk, chemometrics

***Simple example:*** Three different chemical substances are given to patients (each to 5 patients). Some patients die, some not.  Samples (number of patients) are not equal. **How to calculate the rate of risk for each of chemical substances?
Not just simple percentage of dead/alive patients after procedure - but some mean value and confidence interval?**

```
set.seed(5)
binom.data <- sample(c(0,1), 50, replace = TRUE)
my.data <- data.frame(patient = 1:50,
                      chem.s = rep(c("A","B","C"), times = c(12,28,10)),
                      response = binom.data)
head(my.data)
#   patient chem.s response
# 1       1      A        1
# 2       2      A        0
# 3       3      A        0

my.tab <- table(my.data$chem.s, my.data$response); my.tab
#      0  1
#   A  5  7
#   B 18 10
#   C  6  4
```

***Tried solution:***
I found package called *"epitools"* which calculates riskratio.

```
library(epitools)
epitab(my.tab, method="riskratio")

# $tab
#      0        p0  1        p1 riskratio     lower    upper   p.value
#   A  5 0.4166667  7 0.5833333 1.0000000        NA       NA        NA
#   B 18 0.6428571 10 0.3571429 0.6122449 0.3071967 1.220208 0.2959724
#   C  6 0.6000000  4 0.4000000 0.6857143 0.2795865 1.681784 0.6699214
```

On the first sight it seemed that it is the right tool for my example. However, I do not understand why the function do not calculate "lower" and "upper" values for chemical substance "A". What is the reason behind this?

**Are there any other solutions/calculations which would give me not just simple percentage of dead/alive patients after procedure - but some mean value and confudence interval?**

Comment: Because A is baseline, it means everyone needs to compare with A , so A/A = 1 forever; but B/A = 0.357/0.583 = 0.612.

Comment: Thank you @user158565 ! But how to obtain some mean value and confidence interval?

Comment: Whose mean and CI you want?

Comment: I need to express "riskiness" of each substance. Mean "riskiness" and CI (so it could be later tested (f.e. with t-test or something similar), to find significant differences between substances.

Comment: What is riskiness? Probability of death?

Comment: Yes - probability of death (with CI).

Comment: Then the means are the column with header "p1". For CI, maybe you can find it in 'epitools'. If not you can use http://statpages.info/confint.html to get CI.